# Segue not working for dynamically added subview

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, ios5

I've got a storyboard with view A that is inside a navigation controller.  I dynamically add subView B to view A.  Subview B has a table view, and the table view cell has a seque (push) to a detail view.  When I click on the cell, the prepareForSegue method is called, but the detail view is never displayed.  If I switch the seque to a modal, then the detail view gets displayed inside view A, where subView B was.

What I want to happen is the detail view gets pushed onto the navigation controller and when the user hits back on the detail view it goes back to view A, with the subview B embedded.

Below is the code I use for adding the subview:

```
if(!self.homeViewController){
         self.homeViewController = [self.storyboardinstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeView"];        
    }

    if(self.currentViewController != self.homeViewController)
    {            
        [self.view insertSubview:self.homeViewController.view belowSubview:self.tabBar];
        [self.currentViewController removeFromParentViewController];
    }

    self.currentViewController = self.homeViewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code (and storyboard) this may be hard to diagnose.  I have found, however, that sometimes it's a chore to get segues to work properly with dynamically loaded content.  In some cases I have found that using the pushViewController:animated: and popViewController:animated methods of the UINavigationController can be a better approach.  You should be able to access the UINavigationController by through UIViewcontroller.navigationController.

Comment: I've added the code for the addition of the subview.  I was wondering if I would need to do it programatically, but was hoping I would not have to.